# Custom Button Related List URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am using lightning and I'm trying to create a custom button on a related list on the Account object.

My goal is:

1. Add a custom button that says "New Customer Account"
2. When the button is clicked, it should pass in a Record Type ID value and go to the new account record detail screen to avoid the user having to make a record type selection ideally.

I went into the "New Button or Link" area and chose "Content Source = URL", but I am not sure what to put in the box to achieve the above.  What URL syntax would be needed to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you calling a flow from its URL with parameters and the redirect parameter so that you can accomplish this and much more if needed.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_detail_page_buttons.htm&type=5